# Qt: Custom QML module Android APP

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml

I am trying to use a custom QML module in an Android application that I'm developing using Qt.

I have installed de module by adding it to the QML2_IMORT_PATH environment variable and also doing it in the main.cpp file like this:

main.cpp:

```
engine.addImportPath(QStringLiteral("./qml/jbQuick/Charts"));
engine.addImportPath(QStringLiteral("./qml"));
```

Application.pro:

```
QML2_IMPORT_PATH += /qml/jbQuick/Charts
```

The directory structure is like this:

```
trunk
  |- Application.pro
  |- main.cpp
  |- resources/views/main.qml
  |- qml
      |- jbQuick
           |- Charts
                 |- QChart.qml
                 |- qmldir
                 |- QChart.js
```

The application compiles succesfully, but at runtime it gives the error "module "jbQuick.Charts" is not installed".

What is the right way to install the module?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I do use qrc. How should I install the modules in that case? The custom QML modules are already added to the qrc.

Comment: Did you look at this: https://github.com/jwintz/qchart.js/issues/3

Comment: I actually did. That method works when I use the module for a desktop application. However, when deploying to an Android device it does not work.